# str to datetime returns NaT even with correct format passed

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, strptime

I have a column of date strings like '2018-W01'

I have attempted to convert using `pd.to_datetime(urldict[key]['Date'],format ="%Y-W%W",errors='coerce')`, however the column returns NaT if errors are coerced. I have also checked to make sure that the string format is the same throughout the entire column, and have also tested `len` of each entry in the column to ensure that they are uniform.

I have also attempted changing the day of the week/removing it entirely for the `to_datetime` conversion and still cannot return a date. I have also read through the datetime documentation and cannot figure out the error.

The dataframe in question:

```
Date    Vals
2018-W01    0
2018-W02    0
2018-W03    0
2018-W04    0
2018-W05    0
2018-W06    0
2018-W07    0
2018-W08    0
2018-W09    0
2018-W10    0
2018-W11    0
2018-W12    0
2018-W13    0
2018-W14    0
2018-W15    0
2018-W16    0
2018-W17    0
2018-W18    0
2018-W19    0
2018-W20    0
2018-W21    0
2018-W22    0
2018-W23    0
2018-W24    0
2018-W25    0
2018-W26    0
2018-W27    0
2018-W28    0
2018-W29    0
2018-W30    0
2018-W31    0
2018-W32    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the day of the week:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2018-W01']})

pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']+'-1', format='%Y-W%W-%w')
```

Output:

```
0   2018-01-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I should have clarified - I did also try that. I still return NaT for all values.

Comment: @visualnotsobasic thing is, QH used your example and it worked.  Did this example not work for you?  If this example did work, what example strings did not work?  In other words, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It runs as expected on my system (with the given string). Maybe you should check your data and see where the `NaT` occurs and include those strings to your question.

Comment: @QuangHoang I have pasted the dataframe,. Every single value returns NaT.